# MacBook Pro mid 2012 OS X Yosemite hard drive error

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, folders

So I went to my MacBook the other day and the screen shows nothing but a folder with a question mark flashing. It won't reconize my hard drive. I can still hear it spin up and running so is this still a hard drive issue? I have tried all the recovery and Cmd Opt P start-ups and have still gotten nothing.

Comment: you cannot even boot into the recovery partition?

Comment: what happens if you hold down just the option key on boot?

Answer (score 1):

You must try to use low level format, this software run on windows... After the format, it ask choose MBR or GUID... You must select GUID, and install again OS X.